# How to determine the order of the group $\langle a,b,c |a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^2=(bc)^4=(ca)^4=1 \rangle$?

Tags: group-theory

How to determine the order of the group $\langle a,b,c |a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^2=(bc)^4=(ca)^4=1 \rangle$ ?

I have almost no idea how to go on about this . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no general way to go about this. You just have to explore what the relations mean, and work your way from there. For instance, is the group finite? Is it abelian?

Comment: It's a Euclidean Coxeter group. It is virtually abelian and infinite.

Comment: I deleted my original comment since I misread $(bc)^4$ as $(bc)^2$.

Comment: I'm not positive but I think $(abc)^k$ never becomes identity for any $k$.

Comment: @Hamed I am poistive that you right. In fact the subgroup $\langle (abc)^2, acabcb \rangle$ is free abelian and has index $16$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Derek Holt's answer, you can tile the plane with octagons and squares by repeating the following basic unit:

[image]

This gives a Cayley complex for the group, and in particular shows that the group is infinite.